# C shell no idea what this line does (string stuff)

Tags: regex, string, csh

Crappy title, yes. But I honestly have no idea what this particular line of code does, aside from the fact that it probably passes some argument into a perl script. Here's the line:

```
dbget.pl "params::INSTANCES_*" | /bin/sed -e 's/^setenv \(.*\) '"'"'\(.*\)'"'"'; /\1 = \2/ ' > .gen_inst_cache.$$
```

I'm guessing there's a bunch of Regexp going on in here? That's probably why it looks so unreadable in the first place.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script called dbget.pl called with "params::INSTANCES_*" as parameter will generate some output on standard output. This stream will be directed in stdin to sed, that is a stream editor.

Sed will substitute any line beginning with:

```
setenv (something) '(somethingelse)';[space]
```

into:

```
(something) = (somethingelse)[space]
```

The substituted output will be directed to a file called .gen_inst_cache.$$, where $$ is the pid number of your calling shell process.